# Disable system apps without closed-source tools?

Tags: system-apps, disable-app, open-source

After spending more than an hour searching through F-Droid for an app to disable system apps, I gave up. The only thing I was able to find was Disable Manager and that doesn't seem to be able to anything that I can't already do using Android's Settings ui.
I know there are quite a few tools on the Play Store that can disable system apps, but I couldn't find one that is open source.

So I was wondering if it would it be possible to force Android's Settings ui to enable the "Disable/Enable" button for system apps.
Or, if that's not possible, if there is an open source app that would allow me to do it.

My phone: OnePlus One; Running CyanogenMod 13 without gapps; Rooted
Using microG, F-Droid and Xposed...

Comment: Giving that you use microG, you seem at least a bit adept with technology, thus a valid approach would be to use the app **Termux** (available on F-Droid) and disable the interested packages via `su`, then `pm disable <package_name>`. Notice that you'll have to find out packages' names manually.

Comment: Hmm..  CyanogenMod has a terminal app built in, but I would really prefer a graphical user interface.

Comment: You could try the [InstallerOpt](http://repo.xposed.info/module/net.fypm.installeropt) XPosed module (open source, see [Github](https://github.com/afxefx/InstallerOpt)). It even allows you to have the "Uninstall" button (long-press "Disable"), so it should do that as well. Not yet tried myself, though :)